# spam protection needed on php form - not sure how to implement

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a pretty basic PHP site and I want a simple spam protection to stop the spam submissions.
I've found [one](http://99webtools.com/blog/php-simple-captcha-script/) that I like which is a basic 4 character input.  Easy to read, small space requirements.

But it says to use a validate.php for the submission action.
My current form's action is to call a the mailer.php (`<form id="contact-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" class="validate-form">`) which is actually included on page load (`<?php include 'includes/mailer.php'; ?>`).

Can I have two 'actions'?  If not, how can I implement the use of this captcha?

When I try adding `session_start();
if(isset($_POST["captcha"])&&$_POST["captcha"]!=""&&$_SESSION["code"]==$_POST["captcha"])
{
echo "Correct Code Entered";
//Do you stuff`
Just after the opening `<?php` in mailer.php and then `}
else
{
die("Wrong Code Entered");
}` just before the closing `?>`, the whole website just displays "Wrong code entered" on load.

***EDIT:***

I'm having trouble understanding where I need to place the various parts of the code and how to tweak it so it works with the existing mailer script.

My unmodified index.php basically consists of the following:

```
<?php 
    include 'includes/mailer.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">       
</head>
<body>
    <section id="section-home">
        <header>
           <!-- header content -->
           <!-- navigation -->
        </header>
    </section> 
    <section class="banner full-width-container">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- other body content -->
            <div id="contact"> 
                <div id="contact-form-message"><?php print $output; ?></div>
                <form id="contact-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" class="validate-form">
                    <p><span style="color:#f7403a;">Fill in the form below to have an expert contact you</span></p>
                    <div class="form-left">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label for="name" class="assistive control-label">Name:</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Your Name" class="replace-default required type-text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label for="email" class="assistive control-label">Email: </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Your email address" class="replace-default required type-text"  />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end form-left -->
                    <div class="form-right">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label for="subject" class="assistive control-label">Subject: </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="Subject" class="replace-default required type-text"  />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label for="telephone" class="assistive control-label">Telephone number </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="Your phone number" class="replace-default required type-text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end form-right -->
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="message" class="assistive control-label">Message: </label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="replace-default required type-textarea full-width" rows="5" cols="20">The type of enquiry (e.g. Motor Accident) and a brief message</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-stacks" value="Send Message"/>
                            <div id="sending-message"><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer class="full-width-container" id="footer-section">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- footer content -->
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- ============================================== -->
    <script src="js/modernizr-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

And my unmodified mailer.php consist of:

```
<?php

function cleanInput($input){
    $input = trim($input);
    if(strlen($input)>0){
        $input = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($input));
    }
    return $input;
}

$name = '';
$email = '';
$subject = '';
$message = '';
$telephone = '';
$output = '';

if ( isset($_POST['submit']) || isset($_GET['ajax']) == 'true'){
    //set up for form fields
    $name = cleanInput($_POST['name']);
    $email = cleanInput($_POST['email']);
    $subject = cleanInput($_POST['subject']);
    $telephone = cleanInput($_POST['telephone']);
    $message = cleanInput($_POST['message']);
    $output ='';
    $regex = "/^([a-z0-9\\+_\\-]+)(\\.[a-z0-9\\+_\\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\\-]+\\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix";

    //do some basic validation
    if( $name == '' || $name == 'Full Name' ){ $output = '<li class="alert alert-error">Please enter your name.</li>'; }

    if ( !preg_match( $regex, $email ) || $email == 'Email address' ) {
        $output .= '<li class="alert alert-error">Please check that your email address is valid</li>';
    } 

    if( $subject == '' || $subject == 'Subject' ){ $output .= '<li class="alert alert-error">Please enter a subject</li>'; }
    if( $telephone == '' || $telephone == 'Contact number' ){ $output .= '<li class="alert alert-error">Please enter a contact number</li>'; }
    if( $message == '' || $message == 'Your Query' ){ $output .= '<li class="alert alert-error">Please enter a message</li>'; }

    //if there are errors, add them to the list here
    if ( $output!='' ){
        $output = '<div class=""><ul class="unstyled">' . $output . '</ul></div>';    
    }
    //if no errors, try to send the form
    else {
        /*Put the email address to send to here*/
        $to = "email1@domain.com.au";
        $headers = 'From: noreply@domain.com.au' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Cc: '. $email . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Bcc: email2@domain.com.au' . ', ' . 'email3@domain.com.au' . ', ' . 'email4@otherdomain.com.au' . "\r\n";
        $subject = $subject;
        $body = "Name: $name\n\n"
            . "Email: $email\n\n"
            . "Subject: $subject\n\n"
            . "Message: $message"
            ;
        $messageOK = ( mail($to, 'Web Enquiry from the landing page for:  ' . $subject, $body, $headers ));

        //check if the mail was sent or not
        if ( $messageOK ){
            $output = '<div class="alert alert-success"><p>Thank you for getting in touch. We will be in contact soon.</p></div>';
        }
        else {
            $output = '<div class="alert alert-error"><p>We could not send your message. Please try again.</p></div>';
        }
    }
    //if ajax is being used, output the message
    if ( isset($_GET['ajax']) == 'true' ){
        print $output;
    }
}
?>
```

Any information that helps me understand what is required to use this captcha code would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why not just put that code at the top of `mailer.php`? The first argument of the if conditional is checking for the post of the captcha variable which surely wont' occur if the individual in question has just loaded on the page. Furthermore, you can replace `die('wrong code entered')` with `$error = 'The code is incorrect!';`, then later on after the captcha image, you can do `echo isset($error) ? $error : '';`. Just declare `$error = null` at the top .

Comment: Well doesn't '//Do you stuff' imply that rest of my form mailer comes after that and before the 'else'?  Also, I'm not really sure where you're referring to when you say "then later on after the captcha image".  Are you talking about within the form HTML? Same with "Just declare $error = null at the top"... declare how? top of what?   Sorry - I've not got the best understanding of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a random number generated when form is generated, then passing the value using POST AND $_SESSION, and then compare 2 to see if they match. This is for bot protection/spam.

Would you like an example?

EDIT, didn't fully read the question.

What you want to do is to decide whether the page is loaded as POST request, if is not, then display the form, if is, validate $_POST fields and/or send email.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... how do I do that?
Should I edit my question and include the code used in the mailer.php?  Will that help with troubleshooting the issue I'm having?

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
$error = null;
if(isset($_POST["captcha"])&&$_POST["captcha"]!=""&&$_SESSION["code"]==$_POST["captcha"])
{
    echo "Correct Code Entered";
    //Do you stuff`

else
{
    $error = "invalid captcha image, please try again!";
}

//the rest of your HTML
//after the recaptcha image HTML
echo isset($error)? $error: '';
```

This will stop the page from `dieing` because of the failed captcha, and will produe an error message of '`Invalid captcha image'` if the capthc was false.